# How can I pre-select a dropdown option using previously submitted data from database, MySQLI

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have two tables: **orders** and **companies**. Note that both tables has a `company_id` row.

**Orders Table**:
`order_id   |   order_name   |   company_id   |   .....`

**Companies Table**:
`company_id   |   company_name   |   .....`

I have a page with a form that INSERTS data for an order into the orders table in my database. Part of the order is selecting a company from the companies table to go with it, so I use a dropdown for this.

I also have another page with a form that UPDATES that data (an edit page). When I click on the button to bring up the edit page, I'd like to have the previously submitted data in the input fields. With text fields, I just use `value="<?php echo $company['whatever']; ?>"`. However, with dropdown menu's I can't figure out how to pre-select the correct option.

Here is my URL structure:

```
http://website.com/orders.php?page=edit&order_id=1
```

Here is what I have to create my dropdown menu:

```
$getOrder   = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_id = ".$_GET['order_id']);
$getCompany = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM companies ORDER BY company_name ASC");

....

<select class="form-control" name="company_id" id="company_id">
<?php
    if($getCompany) {
        while($company = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getCompany)) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $company['company_id']; ?>">
                <?php echo $company['company_name']; ?>
            </option>
        <?php }
    } 
?>
```

How can I get `selected` on the option that's been previously selected?

Comment: your question is little bit confusing? what you actually want ? show us expected outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$getOrder` has the order details (including *`company_id`*), and `$getCompany` has the company details (including *`company_id`*), then you can compare the two.

If they are equal, `echo` out `selected` as an attribute in the `option`, like so:

```
<select class="form-control" name="company_id" id="company_id">
<?php
    if($getCompany) {

        //Get company ID from Order
        $orderID = $getOrder["company_id"];

        while($company = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getCompany)) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $company['company_id']; ?>"
            <?php 
                //Compare and echo `selected` if they are equal
                if($orderId==$company["company_id"]) echo "selected";
            ?>>
                <?php echo $company['company_name']; ?>
            </option>
        <?php }
    } 
?>
```

That code can be cleaned up, however:

```
<select class="form-control" name="company_id" id="company_id">
<?php
    if($getCompany) {
        $orderID = $getOrder["company_id"];
        while($company = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getCompany)) {
            echo "<option value='{$company['company_id']}".($getOrder["company_id"]==$getCompany["company_id"] ? " selected" : null).">{$company['company_name']}</option>";
        }
    } 
?>
```